# How can I interpret variables on the fly in the shell script?

Tags: json, bash, shell, unix, jq

I'm reading JSON in a shell script using JQ. Here, I'm unable to interpret the variables $HOME, $HOST, $PEMFILE in my shell script on the fly.

JSON File:

```
{
    "script": {
    "install": "${HOME}/lib/install.sh $HOST $PEMFILE",
    "Setup": "${HOME}/lib/setup.sh $HOST $PEMFILE $VAR1 $VAR2"
    }

}
```

Shell Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
examplefile="../lib/example.json"
HOST=ec2-..-...-...-...us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
PEMFILE=${HOME}/test.pem

installScript=($(jq '.script.install' $examplefile))
bash "$installScript"
```

Is there a way I can interpret these variables on the fly without modifying the JSON?

P.S I don't want to use eval.

Comment: You should change the JSON; storing an arbitrary command as a single string is a bad idea. As it is, none of the parameters to be expanded are quoted correctly.

Comment: You also need to use `bash -c`, or `"$installScript"` is going to be treated as the name of a script to execute.

Comment: `installScript=($(jq '.script.install' $examplefile))` is an odd form here -- you're string-splitting a string result into an array, but then in `bash "$installScript"` you're only expanding the first element of that array. And string-splitting is generally buggy in the usage at hand -- see [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: ...which is to say -- `bash -c "$(jq -r '.script.install' "$exampleFile")"` is probably what you're going for. That copy of `bash`, itself, will perform the replacements so long as the variables are `export`ed to the environment -- there's no need to do so ahead-of-time. (If you haven't exported them, do so: `export HOST PEMFILE` and there you are).

Comment: ...oh -- and to be clear: Shell parameter expansion *is not identical* to just doing string replacement. For instance, let's say you have `VAR1=$'"hello" * \' * \'
$(touch /tmp/i-could-have-deleted-your-files) "world"'` -- if you run `echo "$VAR1"`, neither `*` will be replaced with a list of files, and `/tmp/i-could-have-deleted-your-files` won't be created. On the other hand, if you use string replacement before passing content as code -- like you're asking us how to do -- the results of that replacement are parsed as syntax.

Comment: ...so from a security perspective, you're much better off only doing literal substitution of content you've personally written/control, and letting the shell itself do expansion of variables that are coming from external sources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution using [env](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#$ENV,env)  and [gsub](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#gsub(regex;string),gsub(regex;string;flags)) to perform the replacement.

Note that `env` requires the variables to be passed as environment variables as opposed to shell variables.

```
#!/bin/bash

examplefile="../lib/example.json"
HOST=ec2-..-...-...-...us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
PEMFILE=${HOME}/test.pem

export HOST
export PEMFILE
installScript=$(jq -Mr '
   .script.install | gsub("(?<x>[$][{]?\\w+[}]?)"; env[.x|gsub("[${}]+";"")] )
' $examplefile)

echo $installScript
```

Sample Output

```
/home/runner/lib/install.sh ec2-..-...-...-...us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com /home/runner/test.pem
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZFNT4NAEIbv@yvGcRNKKkvk2EobD5iaSGpa44VyWMgqNHzJLraR8tsRWmqqJruTzTtPZt6ZDbiMWhFGOWg1yrCMC4WTGuNMKp4kOEFaL5au05hJHJiDymQEdLFcvwB9dtyHxycHb3AtVFX84WWv/aeBvt6vbo/RwqbRYAZiz9MiEWwr86y9vjKDODODzhohQ@YtToSNlxiSvqgtQstgrDs/t5LGTkhlWCzM06JSgvGUf@UZ38leIYML@@xUdTArRNr3KvJSQV/3/B5gMoy@Pm7IpqPtBxhuCRoBAHbaGxsYOMC7rIIRjuZ3@5lHfa/255vNbuw1/lzHKYjs02P7wwnyaN34Y5wi6j7oRAN6MbHeeer/hv5q37bf)

Comment: Inasmuch as the OP specified even before edits that their input was JSON (as opposed to jq code), I'm not sure that the original version is responsive even to that. The revised version is good, though -- perhaps you might recenter on it (putting it first, if not removing the original outright)?

Comment: This makes sense.  I've replaced my original suggestion.  Thank you!

Comment: (thumbs-up). BTW, adding `set -a` before assigning the variables would have them `export`ed automatically.

Answer (score 6):

It is easy using gnu utility [`envsubst`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/envsubst-Invocation.html):

```
installScript=$(jq -r '.script.install' "$examplefile" | envsubst)
```

Comment: This is one of the two approaches that currently has my +1. That said, on looking back, I'm not sure if it's something that should be recommended without caveat -- it's certainly a fair sight less safe to replace variables with code before parsing the result as a shell command than it is to let the shell do the replacement itself.

Answer (score 3):

### Specific solution

Here's a jq solution to the stated problem, though it will only work for "global" environment variables.

```
def substitute:
  gsub("\\${HOME}"; env.HOME)
  | gsub("\\$HOST"; env.HOST)
  | gsub("\\$PEMFILE"; env.PEMFILE)
  | gsub("\\$VAR1"; env.VAR1)
  | gsub("\\$VAR2"; env.VAR2)
  ;

walk( if type=="string" then substitute else . end )
```

If your jq does not already have `walk/1`, then please either upgrade your jq or snarf the def from https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq

The solution above is a bit brittle but it could easily be robustified or generalized, as shown in the next section.

#### General solution

```
walk(if type == "string"
     then gsub("\\$(?<x>[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]+)"; "\(env[.x])") 
          | gsub("\\${(?<x>[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]+)}"; "\(env[.x])") 
     else . end)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh

TMP=$(mktemp /tmp/$$.XXX)

cat<<E_O_F > $TMP
cat <<EOF
$(cat so-dollar-variables.json)
EOF
E_O_F

. $TMP

/bin/rm "$TMP"
```

Comment: `/tmp/$$.txt` is dangerous -- PIDs are easy for an attacker to predict; someone who controls code running as an unprivileged user (say, `nobody`), if they know that your script is running as `root`, can create a bunch of symlinks with potential/likely PIDs pointing to a root-owned file they want to delete/overwrite.

Comment: Most versions of mktemp I'm aware of require the template to have at least six placeholder/filler characters.

Answer (score 0):

I've been hitting this on and off for years. I think I've finally got a decent pure-bash solution: uses regex matching and indirect parameter substitution

```
# read the file
json=$(< file.json)
echo step 0
echo "$json"

# set the relevant vars, just plain shell variables
HOST=_host_
PEMFILE=_pemfile_
VAR1=_var1_
VAR2=_var2_

# replace '$var' forms
while [[ $json =~ ("$"([[:alnum:]_]+)) ]]; do 
    json=${json//${BASH_REMATCH[1]}/${!BASH_REMATCH[2]}}
done; 
echo
echo step 1
echo "$json"

# replace '${var}' forms
while [[ $json =~ ("$""{"([[:alnum:]_]+)"}") ]]; do 
    json=${json//${BASH_REMATCH[1]}/${!BASH_REMATCH[2]}}
done
echo
echo step 2
echo "$json"
```

Output

```
step 0
{
    "script": {
    "install": "${HOME}/lib/install.sh $HOST $PEMFILE",
    "Setup": "${HOME}/lib/setup.sh $HOST $PEMFILE $VAR1 $VAR2"
    }

}

step 1
{
    "script": {
    "install": "${HOME}/lib/install.sh _host_ _pemfile_",
    "Setup": "${HOME}/lib/setup.sh _host_ _pemfile_ _var1_ _var2_"
    }

}

step 2
{
    "script": {
    "install": "/home/jackman/lib/install.sh _host_ _pemfile_",
    "Setup": "/home/jackman/lib/setup.sh _host_ _pemfile_ _var1_ _var2_"
    }

}
```

The magic is:

1. the regular expression, where I capture both `$VAR` and `VAR`, and

   ```
   [[ $json =~ ("$"([[:alnum:]_]+)) ]]
   # ..........1   2             21
   ```
2. the parameter substitution, where I search for the string `"$VAR"` and replace it with the indirect variable expansion `${!VAR}`

   ```
   ${json//${BASH_REMATCH[1]}/${!BASH_REMATCH[2]}}
   ```